# How to eliminate outliers while calculating standard deviation in a measure in PowerBI measure

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I am relatively new to PowerBI, I want to calculate the Standard Deviation of a parameter eg: Temperature for each batch based on different filters.
This standard deviation has to be calculated by a measure
and it has to be displayed in a Card
But I need to eliminate outliers before calculating std deviation.
How can I Do it in measure?

Outliers condition is Values greater than 99 percentile and less than 1 percentile to be considered as outliers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You need to work with percentile then use function in your logic

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5AxtNdJ5wqk

https://dax.guide/percentile-exc/
https://dax.guide/percentile-inc/

Usefull statistical patterns:
https://www.daxpatterns.com/statistical-patterns/

Comment: Can you also share me a DAX Code, as i am struggling with creating one for the subject topic